# Twig - extending a template in a higher directory, but still in the views folder

Tags: php, twig

This is my folder structure:

```
views
   _templates
       header.twig
   index
       dashboard.twig
```

How can I include the header.twig in my dashaboard.twig file, I've tried:

```
{% extends "base._templates/header.twig" %}
```

I am also using standalone twig and not a framework/symfony

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try something like this:

```
{% extends '../_templates/header.twig' %}
```

if you want to extend template

or if you want to include and render file write:

```
{% include '../_templates/header.twig' %}
```

Comment: Still doesn't seem to be including, no errors or nothing :(

Comment: try with include example :)

Answer (score 0):

It depends on how the Twig template loader is configured. Assuming that it loads from `views` directory, you could use just:

```
{% extends "_templates/header.twig" %}
```

Comment: as mentioned in op, I'm not using symfony